# Smoothness of function 1D sobolev space

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I came across the following statement in my reading and I need some help to understand it

> If $u \in W^{2,2}(a,b)$, then $u\in C^1([a,b])$

What I know is that if $u\in W^{2,2}(a,b)$, then the first weak derivative of $u'$ is in $L^2(a,b)$ and the second order weak derivative $u''$ is also in $L^2(a,b)$ AND that for a function $f \in W^{1,2}(a,b)$, $f$ is in fact continuous on $[a,b]$.

But, then the only conclusion I can get is that the first weak derivative $u'$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. How do I know that the first classical derivative of $u$ exists?

Comment: Why doesn't this follow from Sobolev embedding? With $k=2$, $n=1$, and $p=2$, we have $k>n/p=1/2$. So $u\in C^{k-[n/p]-1,\gamma}(a,b)=C^{1,\gamma}(a,b)$.

Comment: @MattRosenzweig I see. I didn't know the embedding theorem that you referred to. I only knew the embedding theorem for $k =1$

Comment: See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Morrey.27s_inequality).

Comment: Do you know that $u(x)-u(y)=\int_x^y f'(t)\,dt$ for Sobolev functions? @MattRosenzweig: I think that if a (more or less) elementary solution can be found, we should not make the OP fire heavy canons where they are not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know already that the weak derivative (call it $v$ for the moment) is continuous. By definition, $v$ is called a weak derivative if for all $\phi \in C^\infty_0(a, b)$, we have

$$\int_a^b \phi' (x) u(x) dx = - \int_a^b \phi(x) v(x) dx.$$

By approximations, the same formula holds when $\phi$ is of compact support and Lipschitz. Now fix any $c, d\in (a, b)$ and let $\phi_n$ be a Lipschitz function defined as

$$\phi_n (x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x \in \left( c + \frac 1n, d - \frac 1n\right)\\ 0 & \text{if } x\notin (c, d) \\ \text{linear} & 
\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Then we have

$$ n \int_c^{c+ \frac 1n} u(x) dx - n\int_{d-\frac 1n}^d u(x) dx = -\int_a^b \phi(x) v(x) dx.$$

Let $n\to \infty$ gives (as suggested by [@PhoemueX](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1469746/smoothness-of-function-1d-sobolev-space#comment2993159_1469746))

$$u(d) - u(c) = \int_c^d v(x) dx.$$

(Note that the above is true as long as $u\in W^{1, 1}(a, b)$). Now divide by $d-c$ and let $d\to c$, as $v$ is continuous, we have

$$u'(c) = v(c).$$

Thus we have shown that the derivative of $u$ is really the weak derivative $v$.

**Remark** Even when $u$ is only $W^{1, 1} (a, b)$, we can still evaluate the limit
$$\frac{1}{d-c} \int_c^d v(x) dx$$
provided that the limit exist. By the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), this limit exist almost everywhere and is equal to $v(c)$. Thus a $W^{1, 1}(a, b)$ function is differentiable almost everywhere and the derivative is almost everywhere equal to the weak derivative.

Comment: If $W^{1,1}(a,b)$ function ,say $f$, is differentiable in the classical sense almost everywhere, then how can we say that the derivative of $f\in C^1$? In order for a functino to be in $C^1$ in the classical sense, don't we require the derivative of the funcion to be defined at every point, not almost everywhere?

Comment: @hl0202 : Yes, but you have shown that $v$ is continuous (using that $u\in W^{2, 2}$), so the limit exists for all $c\in (a, b)$. (The remark I made are for function in $W^{1, 1}$)

Comment: My apologies for not reading your answer carefully. Btw, when you evaluate the limit $\frac{u(d)-u(c)}{d-c}$ as $d \to c$, any "representative" of $u$ can be used? I mean, $u$ being in $W^{1,1}$ is defined only almost everywhere, but the derivative of ANY representative of $u$ at $c$ is equal to v(c)?

Comment: @hl0202 There is unique representative so that it's continuous. We fix that representative (just like how you say $v$ is continuous).